# Make image thumbnail at runtime while displaying on screen in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, thumbnails

I am performing image conversion in Laravel. What I want is when page loads images which are displaying on the screen will convert into thumbnail and display on the screen. Right now I am able to display images on the screen which is not converted into thumbnail so if I load the page it takes too much time to display image on the screen. I hope someone will help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have done using Imagine library in Laravel 5.
Do this if you want create image thumbnail on fly.

1. integrate this library through https://github.com/orchestral/imagine
2. Add route on web.php to this `Route::get('/images1/{file}', 'ImageController@getImage');`
3. Create an Image controller ImageController.php and paste below code.

   ```
   <?php
   ```

   namespace App\Http\Controllers;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
   use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
   use Session;
   use View;
   use Route;
   use Response;

   class ImageController extends BaseController {

   protected $imagine;

   public function getImage($filename) {

   ```
   //if (!$this->imagine) {
   //    if (!$this->library and  class_exists('Imagick')) {
   //        $this->imagine = new \Imagine\Imagick\Imagine();
   //    } else {
   //        $this->imagine = new \Imagine\Gd\Imagine();
   //    }
   //}
   $this->imagine = new \Imagine\Gd\Imagine();


   // Append the filename to the path where our images are located
   $path = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Eidolon_laravel-Git\\public\\Images\\".$filename; //$filename;
   $filename1 = $filename;
   // Initialize an instance of Symfony's File class.
   // This is a dependency of Laravel so it is readily available.
   $filename = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File($path);

   // Make a new response out of the contents of the file
   // Set the response status code to 200 OK
   $response = Response::make(
       //\File::get($path), 
       $this->resize($filename, 150,150),
       200
   );

   // Modify our output's header.
   // Set the content type to the mime of the file.
   // In the case of a .jpeg this would be image/jpeg
   $response->header(
       'Content-type',
       'image/jpg' //$file->getMimeType()
   );

   // We return our image here.
   //return view('value.pushMessages', $response);
   return $response;
   ```

   }

   /*

   - Resize function.
   - @param string filename
   - @param string sizeString
     *
   - @return blob image contents.
     */
     public function resize($filename, $width, $height) {

     // We can read the output path from our configuration file.
     //$outputDir = \Config::get('assets.images.paths.output');
     $outputDir = "C:\xampp\htdocs\Eidolon_laravel-Git\public\Images\Output";

     // Create an output file path from the size and the filename.
     $outputFile = $outputDir . $filename;

     // If the resized file already exists we will just return it.
     if (\File::isFile($outputFile)) {
         return \File::get($outputFile);
     }

     // File doesn't exist yet, so we will resize the original.
     //$inputDir = \Config::get('assets.images.paths.input');
     //$inputFile = $inputDir . '/' . $filename;

     $inputFile = $filename;
     // Get the width and the height of the chosen size from the Config file.
     //$sizeArr = Config::get('assets.images.sizes.' . $sizeString);
     //$width = $sizeArr['width'];
     //$height = $sizeArr['height'];

     // We want to crop the image so we set the resize mode and size.
     $size = new \Imagine\Image\Box($width, $height);
     $mode = \Imagine\Image\ImageInterface::THUMBNAIL_OUTBOUND;

     // Create the output directory if it doesn't exist yet.
     if (!\File::isDirectory($outputDir)) {
         \File::makeDirectory($outputDir);
     }

     // Open the file, resize it and save it.
     $this->imagine->open($inputFile)
         ->thumbnail($size, $mode)
         ->save($outputFile, array('quality' => 90));

     // Return the resized file.
     return \File::get($outputFile);

   }

   /**

   - @param string $filename
   - @return string mimetype
     */
     public function getMimeType($filename) {

     //// Make the input file path.
     //$inputDir = \Config::get('assets.images.paths.input');
     //$inputFile = $inputDir . '/' .  $filename;
     $inputFile = $filename;
     // Get the file mimetype using the Symfony File class.
     $file = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File($inputFile);
     return $file->getMimeType();

     }
     }

   ?>

now run thee code.